# Resize a border in CSS

Tags: html, css, styles, border

I would like to make a border like in the following photo : [(this one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2EcM.png)

My code is as follows:

```html
<div id="ametg" class="marketorder">
      <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/618876932825677835.png?v=1">
      <font color="yellow"><p>
      Graines en amethyste
      </p>
      <div id="amgp">
        <p>
          Prix : <span>800</span>$/stack
        </p>
      </div>
      <br /><button onclick="orderga">
        Commander
        </button></font>
    </div>
```

And, for the style of the class :

```css
.marketorder{
      border-style: solid
    }
```

Comment: `<font>` is an obsolete element and should no longer be used.

Comment: border:1px solid #ffffff; set a border 1px with white color for example

Comment: I found what I was looking for, sorry for disturbing ya!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code was the good one :

```css
.marketorder{
      border-style: solid;
      width: 150;
      height: 165;
      border: 5px solid black
    }
```

Sorry for disturbing everyone!